# Two or more recursive functions in parallel?

Tags: c++, c++14

Is there any way to do smth like

```
int a() {
    return b();
}

int b() {
    return a();
}
```

in C++?

For example, it is possible in OCaml:

Comment: You can, but it would overflow your stack. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: No, I meant not in the way I showed. Just any way to do parallel recursion like in OCaml

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by parallel recursion? I don't know OCaml and "parallel recursion ocaml" doesn't produce relevant results.

Comment: *"No, I meant not in the way I showed."* - then why did you show it? :)

Comment: In OCaml there is the way to write 
"let rec f x = …
and g x = …"
and both of the functions can call each other

Comment: Yes, you can call `b` from `a` and `a` from `b` in C++, provided that both functions are declared first.

Comment: How could they be declared first at the same time?

Comment: `int a();` `int b();` will declare, but not define, both functions. the definitions can then refer to them

Comment: This is usually called ["mutual recursion"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very simple

```
int b();

int a() {
    return b();
}

int b() {
    return a();
}
```

Comment: Forward-declarations are needed here, headers are not. The two are orthogonal, and bringing up the latter just confuses things IMO.

Comment: Headers are *heavily* tied to forward declaration

Comment: If `a` and `b` are defined in the same source file and used only in that source file, I would forward-declare them in said source-file. Headers are utterly unrelated.